# Tapestry-jQuery error

Tags: jquery, tapestry

I developed a Tapestry application using JQuery.
During deployment, I get an error:

```
cat MPI-alertes.log
[MPI_SYS] 2013-08-30 16:29:38,110 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext :: filterStart] Exception au démarrage                                      du filtre app
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception loading module(s) from manifest jar:file:/usr/local/M2M/RMD_MPIIHM-1.1/httpd1/docs                                     /WEB-INF/lib/tapestry5-jquery-3.3.6.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF: Failure loading Tapestry IoC module class org.got5.tapest                                     ry5.jquery.services.JQueryModule: Error invoking service binder method org.got5.tapestry5.jquery.services.JQueryModule.b                                     ind(ServiceBinder) (at JQueryModule.java:155): org/apache/tapestry5/upload/services/UploadedFile
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.IOCUtilities.addModulesInManifest(IOCUtilities.java:123)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.IOCUtilities.addDefaultModules(IOCUtilities.java:77)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.TapestryAppInitializer.<init>(TapestryAppInitializer.java:124)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.init(TapestryFilter.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:221)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3635)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure loading Tapestry IoC module class org.got5.tapestry5.jquery.services.JQue                                     ryModule: Error invoking service binder method org.got5.tapestry5.jquery.services.JQueryModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at J                                     QueryModule.java:155): org/apache/tapestry5/upload/services/UploadedFile
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.RegistryBuilder.add(RegistryBuilder.java:162)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.IOCUtilities.addModulesInList(IOCUtilities.java:137)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.IOCUtilities.addModulesInManifest(IOCUtilities.java:107)
        ... 21 more
```

Versions are :
tapestry5-jquery-3.3.6
java version "1.5.0_16"
tapestry-core-5.3.7

It's a problem of version no ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had two problems :

- tapestry5-jquery-3.3.6 and tapestry-core-5.3.7 are not compatible.
  I replaced tapestry5-jquery-3.3.6 by tapestry5-jquery-3.3.4.
- JQuery needs tapestry-upload. I added in the pom.xml:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
      <artifactId>tapestry-upload</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.7</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

Now, it works.